# Is there any subtle difference between "to study" and "to learn"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I don't know how to phrase my question better, but I just want to know if there will be any little difference if I directly replace one with the other.

Comment: The difference is not subtle: they have significantly different meanings, as Alenanno has shown.

Comment: I've been studying all day but I don't think I've learned anything...

Comment: I don't think I've ever studied anything accidentally.

Comment: Can anyone clarify the meaning in this particular case?
`He's learning English.` vs `He's studying English.` 
Is there a situation where both sentences mean the same thing? (IE, he's taking classes)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think we can generally divide them like this, although the separation may not always be so clear.

**To study** is the action, (from the dictionary) "*the devotion of time and attention to acquiring knowledge on an academic subject*", so the **activity** itself.

**To learn** is the **result** of that action, or as you can see in the Dictionary again, "*gain or acquire knowledge of or skill in (something) by **study**, experience, or being taught*".

Comment: The two may also be disassociated. You may study without learning, or you may learn without studying.

Comment: Best answer here.

Comment: @Apoorv020: Yes, you're right. And then, thanks Django for the comment and Fumble for the correction. Even after years of "studying", I still make mistakes now and then. It's true when they say you never stop "learning".

Answer (score 18):

Well, you can study without learning, but you can't often learn without studying, at least in academic subjects.

Saying "I studied English" means you took classes in English. It does not necessarily mean you learned anything. Saying "I learned how to tie a clove hitch" means you actually acquired a useful skill.

Comment: Its just as common to *learn* something without deliberately *studying* it, through trial and error or life experience (the "school of hard knocks")

Comment: @Robusto "you can't often learn without studying" is wrong. You learn a lot of things without studying. Even within its context it's wrong. I've learned a lot of English from watching TV, movies and playing games. I don't consider that studying, but English is an academic subject. I also learn a lot from reading on SE and I don't consider that studying either.

Comment: @Erik B: Read the final clause in the sentence you quote.

Comment: Erik B is right. You can learn in many different ways, and to say something as general as "you can't often" is a bit bizarre, unnecessary and open for debate. Otherwise great answer though +1

Comment: The American/"western" idea of "studying" is far different from the eastern idea of studying. "Studying" in eastern culture typically means going out and doing or participating in something. So, @Erik B, watching T.V. and learning English is "studying" the English language by participating in it's use. Just because you aren't sitting in a classroom doesn't mean you aren't studying.

Comment: @md5sum I think the important difference is that I don't watch TV for the purpose of learning. Learning is just a side effect. I could be watching TV to learn English and in that case I would be studying, but I'm not.

Comment: @Robusto I did read the final clause in the sentence and I still think it's incorrect.

Comment: @Erik B - that's why you have to be careful, you could end up studying something without realising - the programs should include warnings

Comment: @mgb you're absolutely right. The ability to filter incoming information, and recognizing when something should not be learned is in my opinion the definition of wisdom, which is entirely separate from intelligence and knowledge.

Answer (score 9):

*To learn* is a much broader term than *to study*. I agree that learning is a result, but it is most often a result of no conscious action on our part. We *learn* from the moment we exist, taking in the lore (related word) of language and customs of those around us through all of our senses. We *learn* every moment of our lives, even while sleeping. When we study (from Latin *studium* ‘zeal, painstaking application’) we make a conscious effort to learn a specific lore. Learning is always the result, even if what we learn is that we can't make heads nor tails of what we are studying. But learning is a given whether we study or not.

Answer (score 6):

**Learning** is **gaining** knowledge.

**Studying** is **pursuing** knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, just because I studied chemistry in high school does not mean I learned it.

Answer (score 1):

I consider the difference more than subtle.

You can study without learning and, yes, you can learn without studying.

Studying is the act of trying to gain information. It generally results in learning. Learning is acquiring new information. It can result from study, but also from everyday life and experiences.

Answer (score 0):

They are very distinct - study implies some kind of focus, while learning can happen by perhaps a broader mechanism.  Usage would depend upon context.  Study also can be a verb or a noun, so that might influence using or avoiding it depending upon context.

FWIW, the term "study" is not used, for example, when discussing work towards degrees in England (at Oxford or Cambridge) - in that case the term used is "read", as in "I read Maths at Cambridge", or "What is Sally reading at Oxford?"

Answer (score 0):

To study, doesn't necessarily mean you'll learn anything. For example, in High School, I was required to study History, and it was very boring and I had trouble paying attention, therefor I did not learn anything.