# "Learn" vs. "study" difference

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs, vocabulary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any subtle difference between “to study” and “to learn”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/is-there-any-subtle-difference-between-to-study-and-to-learn)

What is the difference between "to learn" and "to study"? Can you study without learning? For example, if you study complex math as a subject but you don't understand it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly study without learning, I have students who do that all the time.

Learning implies (to some degree) the *internalization* of the information you are studying.

Studying is simply the devotion of time to a particular subject.